# Submit Rails form with another way instead of button

Tags: javascript, html, ruby

How to use as a submit

index.html.rb

```
<a href="#"  class="submit-link button">Log In</a>
```

application.js

```
$(function() {
    $(".submit-link").click(function() {
        $(this).submit();
    });
```

All I need is ready, but something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use preventDefault to free href from pointing to '#'

```
$(function() {
   $(".submit-link").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');;
      //return false 
   });
```

or return false

Comment: All the same. 
I know what make  <%= f.submit %> is the easiest way. And it work. But I need exactly this way.

Comment: ok, you are trying to submit form... you didn't mention. you need to use jquery to localize your form `$('form').submit()` because `$(this)` refers to your link

Comment: Yes. I see something like this 
<button class="submit-link">
<a href="#"  class="form">Log In</a>
</button>
And it work. But again it button. Or I just can't understand simple things.

Comment: if you want to send form when `$(".submit-link")` is clicked you need to call function on your form. Form has id so grab this form and call submit `$('#form-name').submit() ` when your link clicked. With button case : `button` has type `submit`or button has some additional events on that triggers the form. `

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$(function() {
   $(".submit-link").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
   });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no it do nothing.

Comment: @AlexandrBalahontsev my bad its supposed tobe `$(this).attr('href')`, updated post